# how to use broadcast receiver on receive

Tags: android

i have a project and when i run the application,one service should be active and when the device is turned on,my android service should be active.
The project runs in emulator successfully but in my phone when i turn on the device it doesn't works!

my broadcast receiver :

```
 public class BroadcastReceiverOnTurnedOn extends BroadcastReceiver {
 @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
      context.startService(startServiceIntent);
  }
 }
```

i added :

```
  <receiver android:name="com.dariran.BroadcastReceiverOnTurnedOn">  
    <intent-filter>  
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />  
    </intent-filter>  
  </receiver>
```

to appliation tag on Manifest.xml and

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You are registering a `BroadcastReceiver` not a `Service`. Services will generally run in the background all of the time (if memory and resources permit).

Your broadcast receiver activates only when the device is rebooted - and your emulator "boots" every time you start it up. Your phone does not "boot" when the app is installed.

You should either register for events like "app installed" or else actually implement a service, like here:

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html

Comment: you mean that i should define and implement service on an activity firt??

Comment: Yes - you are running a process after the user leaves your activity.. which means you want a service to handle the results and then, if the user is still in your app, have the service notify the activity

Comment: i undrestand, i installed application on phone memory and rebooted device service worked, now how can i run it when appliation is on external memory?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that once you install the app on device it should be started once by clicking app icon then only boot receiver will receive boot event on subsequent reboots calls.

Comment: it start on onCreate on first activity but when i run once the application it works and when i reboot my device it not work

Comment: can you check if you have registered service in manifest file ? or just place log in boot receiver that at least code executes inside boot receiver.

Answer (score 0):

i undrestand that if i install app in internal storage in works successfully even device rebooted but when i install the app on external storage and then reboot device it not work

i have a project that when run application one service be active and when device be turn on my android service be active. the project run in device's internal memory successfully but when i install it on external memory and reboot my device again don't work!

for first i call my service in first acitivity and it works, but when i reboot my device it doesn't work !

my activity :

```
public class FirstClass extends Activity 
{
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
  {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.first);
   final Handler handler = new Handler();
   handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() 
   {
     public void run()
    {
        startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class));
        startActivity(new Intent(FirstClass.this, MainActivity.class));
        finish();
    }
 },5000);
}
 /////////////////////////////////////////////////
}
```

my broadcast receiver :

```
 public class BroadcastReceiverOnTurnedOn extends BroadcastReceiver {
 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
    context.startService(startServiceIntent);
  }
 }
```

i added :

```
  <service
    android:name="com.dariran.MyService"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true" >
  </service>
  <receiver android:name="com.dariran.BroadcastReceiverOnTurnedOn"
    android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter android:priority="1">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" /> 
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action  android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_AVAILABLE" />
    </intent-filter>
 </receiver>to appliation tag on Manifest.xml and 

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

i added this code to my service class to put a filter to recognize the external storage but don't work again :(

```
 @Override
 public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
   try {

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_AVAILABLE);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_AVAILABLE);
    BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiverOnTurnedOn();
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

   } catch (Exception e) {
   }
 }
```